# validation of my code json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, validation

I am developping a simple application in AngularJs in the first time I create a script js but later I need to change it to json file so I need to validate this code json :

```
[{
      "type": "line",
      "plotarea": {
        "adjust-layout":true /* For automatic margin adjustment. */
      },
      "scale-x": {
        "label":{ /* Add a scale title with a label object. */
          "text":"échelle essence gazoile",
        },
        /* Add your scale labels with a labels array. */
        "labels":["sub01","sub02","sub02"]
      },
      "series": [
        {"values":[1,8,1]},//here the prices of city selected
        {"values":[14,13,14]}//here the qte of city selected
      ],

        "name": "city A",
        "elements": [{
          "id": "c01",
          "name": "name1",
          "price": "15",
          "qte": "10"
        }, {
          "id": "c02",
          "name": "name2',
          "price": "18,
          "qte": "11"
        }, {
          "id": "c03",
          "name": "name3",
          "price": "11",
          "qte": "14"
        }],
        "subsities": [{
          "name": "sub A1",
          "elements": [{
            "id": "sub01",
            "name": "nameSub1",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "14"
          }, {
            "id": "sub02",
            "name": "nameSub2",
            "price": "8",
            "qte": "13"
          }, {
            "id": "sub03",
            "name": "nameSub3",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "14"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "sub A2",
          "elements": [{
            "id": "ssub01",
            "name": "nameSsub1",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "7"
          }, {
            "id": "ssub02",
            "name": "nameSsub2",
            "price": "8",
            "qte": "1"
          }, {
            "id": "ssub03",
            "name": "nameSsub3",
            "price": "4",
            "qte": "19"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "sub A3",
          "elements": [{
            "id": "sssub01",
            "name": "nameSssub1",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "11"
          }, {
            "id": "sssub02",
            "name": "nameSssub2",
            "price": "2",
            "qte": "15"
          }, {
            "id": "sssub03",
            "name": "nameSssub3",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "15"
          }]
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "city B",
        "elements": [{
          "id": "cc01",
          "name": "name11",
          "price": "10",
          "qte": "11"
        }, {
          "id": "cc02",
          "name": "name22",
          "price": "14",
          "qte": "19"
        }, {
          "id": "cc03",
          "name": "name33",
          "price": "11",
          "qte": "18"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "city C",
        "elements": [{
          "id": "ccc01",
          "name": "name111",
          "price": "19",
          "qte": "12"
        }, {
          "id": "ccc02",
          "name": "name222",
          "price": "18",
          "qte": "17"
        }, {
          "id": "ccc03",
          "name": "name333",
          "price": "10",
          "qte": "5"
        }]
      }];
```

A JSON Validator tells me that my code json is not correct.

Please anybody could help me !

Comment: Remove comments /* --- */, //

Comment: Also you aren't allowed to have single quote `'` so replace them with `"`

Comment: `"name": "name2',
          "price": "18,` replace with  `"name": "name2",
          "price": "18",`

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad yes you're right

Comment: Thank you so much for you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you have comments in your JSON. This is not allowed in pure json.

In addition you have some syntax errors:

- Line 8 :`"text": "échelle essence gazoile",` the `,` has to be removed because it is the last property of the object
- Line 26: `"name": "name2',` change the singlequote to a doublequote
- Line 27: `"price": "18,`: add a doublequote at the end
- Last line: `}];` remove the semicolon

**This is your valid json:**

```
[{
    "type": "line",
    "plotarea": {
        "adjust-layout": true
    },
    "scale-x": {
        "label": {
            "text": "échelle essence gazoile"
        },
        "labels": ["sub01", "sub02", "sub02"]
    },
    "series": [{
        "values": [1, 8, 1]
    }, {
        "values": [14, 13, 14]
    }],

    "name": "city A",
    "elements": [{
        "id": "c01",
        "name": "name1",
        "price": "15",
        "qte": "10"
    }, {
        "id": "c02",
        "name": "name2",
        "price": "18",
        "qte": "11"
    }, {
        "id": "c03",
        "name": "name3",
        "price": "11",
        "qte": "14"
    }],
    "subsities": [{
        "name": "sub A1",
        "elements": [{
            "id": "sub01",
            "name": "nameSub1",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "14"
        }, {
            "id": "sub02",
            "name": "nameSub2",
            "price": "8",
            "qte": "13"
        }, {
            "id": "sub03",
            "name": "nameSub3",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "14"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "sub A2",
        "elements": [{
            "id": "ssub01",
            "name": "nameSsub1",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "7"
        }, {
            "id": "ssub02",
            "name": "nameSsub2",
            "price": "8",
            "qte": "1"
        }, {
            "id": "ssub03",
            "name": "nameSsub3",
            "price": "4",
            "qte": "19"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "sub A3",
        "elements": [{
            "id": "sssub01",
            "name": "nameSssub1",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "11"
        }, {
            "id": "sssub02",
            "name": "nameSssub2",
            "price": "2",
            "qte": "15"
        }, {
            "id": "sssub03",
            "name": "nameSssub3",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "15"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "name": "city B",
    "elements": [{
        "id": "cc01",
        "name": "name11",
        "price": "10",
        "qte": "11"
    }, {
        "id": "cc02",
        "name": "name22",
        "price": "14",
        "qte": "19"
    }, {
        "id": "cc03",
        "name": "name33",
        "price": "11",
        "qte": "18"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "city C",
    "elements": [{
        "id": "ccc01",
        "name": "name111",
        "price": "19",
        "qte": "12"
    }, {
        "id": "ccc02",
        "name": "name222",
        "price": "18",
        "qte": "17"
    }, {
        "id": "ccc03",
        "name": "name333",
        "price": "10",
        "qte": "5"
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with comments and some of values doesn't contain `,` and some contains in the last value.(For example : `'json': {
    'value1': 14,
    'value2':14, // , is not allowed in the last line
}`) Also last line can't contain `;` after `}]`
Use this for validation [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

This is correct json:

```
[{
    "type": "line",
    "plotarea": {
        "adjust-layout": true
    },
    "scale-x": {
        "label": {
            "text": "échelle essence gazoile"
        },

        "labels": ["sub01", "sub02", "sub02"]
    },
    "series": [{
        "values": [1, 8, 1]
    }, {
        "values": [14, 13, 14]
    }],

    "name": "city A",
    "elements": [{
        "id": "c01",
        "name": "name1",
        "price": "15",
        "qte": "10"
    }, {
        "id": "c02",
        "name": "name2",
        "price": "18",
        "qte": "11"
    }, {
        "id": "c03",
        "name": "name3",
        "price": "11",
        "qte": "14"
    }],
    "subsities": [{
        "name": "sub A1",
        "elements": [{
            "id": "sub01",
            "name": "nameSub1",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "14"
        }, {
            "id": "sub02",
            "name": "nameSub2",
            "price": "8",
            "qte": "13"
        }, {
            "id": "sub03",
            "name": "nameSub3",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "14"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "sub A2",
        "elements": [{
            "id": "ssub01",
            "name": "nameSsub1",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "7"
        }, {
            "id": "ssub02",
            "name": "nameSsub2",
            "price": "8",
            "qte": "1"
        }, {
            "id": "ssub03",
            "name": "nameSsub3",
            "price": "4",
            "qte": "19"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "sub A3",
        "elements": [{
            "id": "sssub01",
            "name": "nameSssub1",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "11"
        }, {
            "id": "sssub02",
            "name": "nameSssub2",
            "price": "2",
            "qte": "15"
        }, {
            "id": "sssub03",
            "name": "nameSssub3",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "15"
        }]
    }]
    }, {
    "name": "city B",
    "elements": [{
        "id": "cc01",
        "name": "name11",
        "price": "10",
        "qte": "11"
    }, {
        "id": "cc02",
        "name": "name22",
        "price": "14",
        "qte": "19"
    }, {
        "id": "cc03",
        "name": "name33",
        "price": "11",
        "qte": "18"
    }]
    }, {
    "name": "city C",
    "elements": [{
        "id": "ccc01",
        "name": "name111",
        "price": "19",
        "qte": "12"
    }, {
        "id": "ccc02",
        "name": "name222",
        "price": "18",
        "qte": "17"
    }, {
        "id": "ccc03",
        "name": "name333",
        "price": "10",
        "qte": "5"
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a C Style or C# style comments inside a json document.As a matter of fact you cannot have any comments inside a json document
You can validate your json document on http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this# http://jsonlint.com/

this will validate your json and also gives you error where you are doing mistakes